# In Jmeter , how to wait for a previous sampler(JDBC Request) to finish and then start the new sampler Request(Http request)

Tags: java, jmeter

So I have a case where I need to do Database operation everytime before the http request sampler. Issues is http request is taking time to execute, and db requests are in ThreadPool. So http request is failing due to that.

Can somebody help me with how to wait for previous sampler to complete and then run the next sampler.

PS Tried with preProcesser also, but same issue

Comment: What do you mean by "db requests are in ThreadPool" ?

Answer (score 1):

By default JMeter runs samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) so if you put HTTP Request sampler **under** the JDBC Request sampler JMeter will execute JDBC first and HTTP second.

If samplers live in different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you still can configure one sampler depend on another with [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin which is basically a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) queue so you can put something into it in 1st Thread Group when the JDBC Request sampler is executed and in the 2nd Thread Group wait for queue size to change and once done - execute the HTTP Request sampler.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication plugin via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Inter Thread Communication Plugin Manager]

Comment: Its in the same thread Group , and I have Thread Count as 10 . So only 4-5 thread s are passed and other fail as http request takes hell lot of time to execute and all the threads of JDBC request are already executed.

Comment: Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) so within one session the samplers will be executed sequentially. If you want first execute all JDBC samplers by all threads and then execute all HTTP samplers by all threads you need to add [Synchronizing Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as children and set count to 10.